# In ArcGIS Online, how to configure layer actions to use a map to filter a table for a chart?

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-layer, actions, dashboard

In ArcGIS Online, I've created a dashboard. In the Dashboard, there is a webmap. I also have a chart. It IS possible to use the map to filter the chart, using Layer Actions (configure gear, layer actions on the lower left, select filter). Both map and chart are based on the SAME file. But what I'd like to do (if it's possible) is to use the map to filter a DIFFERENT data file, if the two fields have a common data file.

I've currently got it set where a table is related to the shapefile in the webpage, but it's proving laggy and awkward.

Answer (score 0):

Proved to be surprisingly easy: ArcGIS has a native way to do it, and it works far better than using a relate in the webmap: [image: Filter-thing]